# What tools can I use to help me calculate Damage in combat?

Tags: combat, rogue-trader, tool-recommendation

Whenever I am in combat I find it really hard to calculate the damage my NPCs receive, because it has a lot of small steps: account the damage the PC did, subtract any Pen the PC's weapon may have to my NPCs AP, then subtract any AP left to the raw damage the PC did, and then subtract my NPC's TB to whatever damage is left.

The calculations are simple, but I get lost easily due to the amount of steps and the pressure I feel because I don't want combat to be slowed down, so I could really use a program that could do my bidding. I've tried Excel sheets, but I'd have to change numbers for every weapon and I'm not very skilled at that program either.

This program should have: An NPC "section" where I could choose how much AP and TB does it have, another "section" where I put the weapon's characteristics (Pen, special rules), and finally a wound counter of some sort that showed me how much HP does the NPC have left. The best would be the ability to save templates with different weapons and NPCs. And if I can dream, it would also display the appropriate Critical Damage text for every -1 to -10+ wound.

Comment: I think your math can be simplified, too. From your text, I gather that you do: `Total = Damage-max(0,(Pen-AP))-TB`, which I assume is how the game works (I take your word on that). Note however, that addition is usually much faster than subtraction. To simplify the math, do this: `If Pen>=AP: Total = Damage-TB; Else: Total = Damage+Pen-(AP+TB)`. Technically, both are identical, but the latter is more structured, which can help tremendously with math.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No tool like this exists for Rogue Trader...**

I spent about half an hour searching around on google, forums, and the official Rogue Trader site to see if there was anything approaching what you described and there is not. In fact the only tool of any kind I could find was for [star system generation](http://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/82650-rogue-trader-generator-tools-released/) (and everything within)

**However, you shouldn't be the one doing all the math and having to remember all the details...**

As a GM (in just about any game) your primary jobs are as follows:

1. Plan, Create, and Describe the setting and events as they unfold.
2. Be the antagonist to your Players when you are controlling NPCs in combat.
3. Adjudicate actions (i.e. your players say I want to do X, you tell them thats *insert name* skill check, you get +2 for your *insert creative idea* roll to see if you succeed)

I think the issue is that you see the system math for everyone as your responsibility. **IT IS NOT**. System math is a shared responsibility between the GM and the players. In the example you cite above it seems like your players roll for damage and then check out letting you compute everything.

Instead, during combat when its a Player's turn and they roll an attack against one of your NPCs and roll damage it is their responsibility to call out damage, penetration values, and any special abilities their weapons may or may not have. Meanwhile you are simply looking at the stats for the NPC being attack and comparing the numbers the player is calling out to you allowing you to quickly do the math.